# Java Only Running Part of Code

Tags: java, awt

Part of a simple Java application I have draws out two strings within a frame. The first string is rendered, however, the second is not.

```
import java.awt.*;
//Begin troublesome section    
class NewFrame extends Frame {

  public void paint (Graphics g)
  {
    g.drawString ("Foo", 70, 70);
  }

 public void paint2 (Graphics g)
  {
    g.drawString ("Bar", 600, 600);
  }

}
//End troublesome section
public class FooBar {

  public static void main (String[] argv)
  {
    NewFrame nf = new NewFrame ();

    nf.setTitle ("Foo Bar");
    nf.setResizable (true);
    nf.setBackground (Color.cyan);
    nf.setSize (700, 700);

    nf.setVisible (true);
  }
}
```

The part of the code in question is what is noted as the "troublesome section".

Comment: When do you expect `paint2()` to be called?

Comment: the code that you show us does not show where either paint or paint2 are called.

Comment: Java programs are **not** scripts

Comment: @Matteo I've been doing too much JS, haha. Would code be the correct term?

Comment: Why AWT rather than Swing?  See my answer on [Swing extras over AWT](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6255978/418556) for many good reasons to abandon using AWT components.  If you need to support older AWT based APIs, see [Mixing Heavyweight and Lightweight Components](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/mixing-components-433992.html).

Comment: @AndrewThompson I will definitely try out Swing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The method `paint` is called automatically by Java to paint the window. See the method [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#paint%28java.awt.Graphics%29)

The method `paint2` is not standard and will not be invoked automatically.

Either

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);
    g.drawString ("Foo", 70, 70);
    g.drawString ("Bar", 600, 600);
}
```

or

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);
    g.drawString ("Foo", 70, 70);
    paint2(g);
}

public void paint2(Graphics g) {
    g.drawString ("Bar", 600, 600);
}
```

Comment: Remember, when overriding `paint()` in `Frame` or `paintComponent()` in `JPanel`: You must call the superclass method. i.e. `super.paint(g);` and `super.paintComponent(g);` respectively.

Comment: Don't you need to pass `Graphics g` to `paint2()` in the second snippet?

Answer (score 4):

That's hardly surprising: `paint` is being called by a base class function (somewhere in the implementation of one of the methods in `Frame`: put a breakpoint in `paint` and, using your debugger, look at the call stack when the breakpoint is reached), `paint2` is not called by anything.

Why not call `paint2` from `paint` yourself? Better still, incorporate the code from `paint2` to `paint`. So you don't get yourself into this kind of pickle again, add an `@Override` *annotation* to `paint`; not forgetting to call `paint` in the parent class:

```
@Override
public void paint (Graphics g)
{
    super.paint(g); /*your first job is to call the base method*/
```